# How to orient components in an eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

Given the default container given to me from an Eclipse View, I wish to orient an AWT frame and an SWT Label. I want the SWT Label to be on the top, and the AWT Frame to be directly below it. For some reason, I cannot get the SWT Label to draw outside of where the frame is. I  want them to be separate, yet the RowLayout doesn't appear to be putting the components into isolated rows.

SWT Label undesirably being placed inside of the AWT Frame:
[image]

Code within the Plugin's View:

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

    container = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
    RowLayout rowLayout = new RowLayout();
    //I have tried toggling many of the RowLayout properties but this has no effect on placing the label outside of the AWT Frame.
    container.setLayout(rowLayout);

    Label topLabel = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
    topLabel.setText("MY NEW LABEL");

    frame = org.eclipse.swt.awt.SWT_AWT.new_Frame(container);
    frame.setFocusable(true);
    frame.setFocusableWindowState(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

`RowLayout` *never* puts components into separate rows, it puts them into *one* row. You can create it with `SWT.VERTICAL` style so that the row goes from top to bottom instead of left to right. However, the screenshot is still incorrect. It may help to have the frame as the only child of its own composite:

```
container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
RowLayout rowLayout = new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL);
container.setLayout(rowLayout);

Label topLabel = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
topLabel.setText("MY NEW LABEL");

Composite frameContainer = new Composite(container, SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
frame = org.eclipse.swt.awt.SWT_AWT.new_Frame(frameContainer);
frame.setFocusable(true);
frame.setFocusableWindowState(true);
```